# Cannot have multiple charts in one HTML page - d3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, visualization

I need to have two same group bar charts, one below another.

I just copied the code and defined two divs and two SVGs

I want to have [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/9qYIlLs53NTu5gyC0bAw?p=preview) chart twice.

But I have [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/SssNwVZSQiRbw1ea4epT?p=preview) as a result.

Can someone tell me what is my problem?

**HTML**:

```
<div class="svg-div">
<svg id="svg1" width="1000" height="500"></svg>
<svg id="svg2" width="1000" height="500"></svg>
<script src = "barchart.js"> </script>
</div>
```

**Javascript**:

```
//SVG for the second chart

var svg2 = d3.select('#chart1').append("svg2").attr('width', 800).attr('height', 550),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 40},
    width = +svg2.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg2.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg2.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have tons of duplicated variables here! That simply won't work.

The correct way to fix this is renaming all the variables (if the charts are substantially different) or creating a function that you call multiple times (if the charts are the same and only the data changes, for instance).

Meanwhile, here is a quick and lazy solution: I wrapped your *two* codes inside IIFEs:

```
(function chart1(){
    //code here for chart1
}())

(function chart2(){
    //code here for chart2
}())
```

Here is the plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/IoTUkqrGWmunrSW9x9ls?p=preview

Again, this is not the correct way to fix this, I'm doing this only for you to see that variables are scoped. I suggest that you change the variables or, even better, if the code is the same for both charts, simply put all of it inside a function that you call twice (with the same arguments or with different arguments, that's up to you). Like this:

```
function draw(selector){
    var svg = d3.select(selector).append("svg")
    //etc...
}

draw("#chart1");
draw("#chart2");
```

Here is the corresponding plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/7bZhmmMV1CjUgx7v59wY?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

```
var svg2 = d3.select('#chart1').append("svg").attr('width', 800).attr('height', 550),
margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 40},
width = +svg2.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
height = +svg2.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
g = svg2.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

I made a small change that should make it work. .append() needs a valid element so just append an svg.

Comment: Its seems as though it creates 2 charts but the first one no longer has anything inside the SVG now.

Comment: Thank you, but as you said it still shows only one of them, not both. Do you know how I can make it work?

Comment: Why not use class instead of ID?